# ext. news extended with two fields: now strange cache behaviour

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

typo3 7.6.10
news 4.3.0

I have a strange cache behaviour:

I made an extension which extends the news model with a select field "teasercolor" and a checkbox "showimage".

http://pastebin.com/ViPEemr9

In the fluid view, I use these news fields like this:
`<div class="overlay {newsItem.teasercolor}">`

This seemed to work. But after a while, my teasercolor class disappears from the code. Same with the checkbox value.

When I then delete the fe cache in the backend, it re-appears.

After a while it disappears again. Never seen such a behaviour again.

Has somebody an idea?

Comment: in TYPO 7.6 you should use the Override TCA files, not ext_tables.php. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/mktools/Utilities/TcaOverrides/Index.html

Comment: Please post your code inside the question, not in pastebin. 40 lines of code isn't that difficult to copy to your question.

Answer (score 0):

have you a clean dependency to ext:news?

do you use Resources/TCA/Overrides/....php?

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html

Comment: no i didn't use TCA/Overrides.

i made it from this tutorial
http://keinerweiss.de/525-die-extbase-extension-news-um-ein-feld-erweitern.html

Comment: ext_tables.php should not be used for table enhancements any more. the information might get lost. the concatenated information of all ext_tables.php is stored in another cache, included at another time then the concatenaton of all Resources/TCA/... definitions.

Comment: have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.